# Redirect Static Request Express Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, proxy

I am making a game using websockets.

I own 3 Nodejs servers: `game1.website.com`, `game2.website.com`, `website.com`.

I want `game1` and `game2` to only handle game logic (websocket communication) while `website.com` handles all http requests.

---

Players go to `game1.website.com` and connect with `game1.website.com` server with websocket.

If players request static files (images, js, css), I want `website.com` to do the processing. `game1.website.com` should process the least possible.

How can I achieve that? The latency for the websocket must stay minimal. I don't mind if latency for http requests is longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users go to `website.com` to access your site. This returns the webpages required for use; Content like HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc. The JavaScript which connects to the websocket server only has to connect to `game1.website.com` and/or `game2.website.com`.

`game1.website.com` and `game2.website.com` are just websocket servers that do the processing as necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Using socket.io, this was done via `socket = io('http://game1.website.com:80');`